# android unlock screen intent?

Tags: android, screen, locking, android-intent

Is there an intent that is fired when a user unlocks their screen?  I want my app to adjust the brightness when the screen turns on, but the problem im running into is that the screen on intent is fired on the lock screen and it does not adjust the display on that screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `disableKeyguard` method in the [KeyguardLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html) class.

Comment: I don't think this directly answers the question. As this seems to be a method of unlocking the screen rather than getting notified when the screen has been unlocked.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` is broadcasted after the user unlocks:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT

Note that this is a protected broadcast and if the user is using a lock screen replacement such as `WidgetLocker` or `NoLock` the `USER_PRESENT` may not be sent or may be sent at the wrong time.

For detecting `WidgetLocker`'s unlock see:
http://teslacoilsw.com/widgetlocker/developers

Answer (score 9):

Add the receiver in menifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Create a broadcast receiver which works to open app when phone is unlocked.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class); 
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure it will work.