# How to make android app to first thing to be launched after Unlocking phone

Tags: android

I need urgent help to make a android app to be launched after unlocking the phone.

I want always on top kind of functionality in App, Means whenever phone unlocked by the user , they should see the app.

is it Possible??

Thank in Advance

Comment: I think you should not do this without taking user's permission.

Comment: if your app isn't a home screen, it sounds annoying..

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  You could approximate it by having your app replace the home screen/launcher, but the user will still be able to revert to the original one through the settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803069/android-unlock-screen-intent) discusses that there is an `Intent` Object that you can capture using a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). The `BroadcastReceiver` can then run the code you need or launch an `Activity`, etc.