# android: launch my app on unlocking the device

Tags: android, android-intent

i m having a problem in **launching my app after unlock**.

I am new to android programming. I am building a ***Face Recognition unlock System for Android***. Anyone, tell me any tutorial or any help about launching my app on just unlocking the device. I am unable to get any help from google. So **Please**, anyone help me as soon as it is possible.

As my Project is Face Recognition Unlock. It means that if a person unlocks the device, it must launch my app for the purpose of face detection. I have done much work of face detection, but cant launch my app on unlock.
JnR

Comment: But you _have_ planned for some extra time to understand the concepts of the new platform, haven't you? -- You may want to look at [Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT), though. But I suspect that you may really have a requirement which differs from what you describe.

Comment: Here are good links about lock screens:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4666109/1387438  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14890282/1387438

Comment: may be you are right, i did edit my question, so you can see a detailed question.. and thanks for response.
JnR

Answer (score 1):

There is an intent ACTION_USER_PRESENT which is broadcasted after user unlocks. 
here is a [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)

also visit on this [thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803069/android-unlock-screen-intent), look similar to your problem