# Start service when device is unlocked

Tags: android

I want to start service only when device is unlocked. I've tried this code but it didn't work.Can somebody explain me what do I do wrong?And what should I do?

```
if( myKM.isKeyguardLocked()==false) {
    startService(intent);
    Log.i("Point ","5");
} else {
    Log.i("Point ","6");
    stopService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android unlock screen intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803069/android-unlock-screen-intent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - detect phone unlock event, not screen on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a Broadcast Receiver for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`

No you can check in `onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)` as below -

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
// device unLocked
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand. If I use this which action should I do ? Start service or activity?

Comment: @S.Drumble3: You can start the service.